# Fourier transform of the sinc function using the duality theorem

Tags: fourier-transform

> Find the Fourier transform in $F$ of $$
> f(t)=\frac{\sin(\pi t/T)}{\pi t/T}
> $$

It is known that:
$$
F\{u(t+\tau)-u(t-\tau)\}=\frac{\sin(2\pi F \tau)}{\pi F}
$$
Using the duality theorem:
$$
F\{F(t)\}=2\pi f(-2\pi F)
$$

I get

$$
F\{f(t)\}=2\pi T [u(-2\pi F+1/2T)-u(-2\pi F-1/2T)]
$$

How do I proceed from here so that the final answer would be
$$
T\left[u\left(-F+\frac{1}{2T}\right)
-
u\left(-F-\frac{1}{2T}\right)
\right]
$$

Comment: There are different kinds of Fourier transform, namely ordinary frequency, angular frequency and unitary frequency. Check if you are using the corresponding one in duality theorem.

Comment: Ok thank you, Im not aware of the different versions for the duality theorem. I'll check it out